# Showing the set $A$ (set of poles) of a meromorphic function is countable

Tags: complex-analysis

I want to prove the following:
Let $f$ be meromorphic on the open connected set $\Omega\subseteq\mathbb{\hat{C}}$, and let $A$ be the set of its poles in $\Omega$ then $A$ is a countable set.

I'm having trouble with how to prove this. 
What I have so far:

Suppose that $A$ is uncountable then 
there exists $r>0$ such that $D(0,r)$ contains uncountably many poles.
But since each $x,y\in A$ is isolated, there exists an $r_x>0$ such that $D(x,r_x)$ contains no other point of $A$. (That is there exists $r_x,r_y>0$ such that $D(x,r_x)\cap D(y,r_y)=\emptyset$ when $x\neq y.$)

I'm not sure what to do from here since it seems as though this should be impossible as you have uncountably infinite amount of disjoint disks in a disk with finite radius.

Comment: By definition, $A$ is discrete in $\mathbb C$. So, do you see that a discrete set in $\mathbb C$ is countable? You can do it by making an injection from $A$ to $\mathbb Q \times \mathbb Q$. For each $x \in A$ just take a rational point inside the disc $D(x,r_x)$ .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take your collection $D(x,r_x)$, and a choose a rational number (complex number with rational parts) in each of them. Since each will be assigned a different rational number, and there are countably many rationals, there are only countably many $D(x,r_x)$, so $A$ couldn't be uncountable.

Answer (score 1):

$\Omega$ is the countable union of compact sets. If $A$ were uncountable, then one of these compact sets, call it $K,$ would contain infinitely many elements of $A.$ By compactness, there would then be a sequence in $A\cap K$ converging to some $z_0 \in K.$ The singularity of $f$ at $z_0$ is therefore not isolated, contradicting the definition of meromorphic.